# Password creation to access app

Tags: android

Think this is kind of a hard question to phrase correctly. Once the user downloads the app, i want to create a password for them to have to input a password on first time startup. When this password in input correctly, the user never has to input it again and has full access to the app from then on. Can anyone point me in the right direction of a tutorial or guide me in how this can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you authenticating? I mean how do you get to know the user has entered the correct password. Or you want to allow the user to create an account? Like signup?

Comment: Once the user enters the password, this password is matched to a list of passwords. If it matches one of the legitimate passwords, somehow it would be hardcoded into the app so that it was there on startup each time. Do you get what i mean or did i make a balls of the question?

Comment: If the user provides the correct password then store the value in `SharedPreferences`. Then everytime in `onCreate()` check if the value if present in `SharedPreferences` or not. If it is present then don't ask him to enter the credentials again otherwise ask him to enter.

Comment: Thankyou. Just wondering for future, did you mark me down because the question was confusing?

Comment: I didn't down vote this question. Someone else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the easiest implementation, you can use SharedPreference. Store some value named "isFirstTime" or something with a value true. On your launcher activity, check whether this value is false or true. When user will first launch the app, this will be false. Display your password or call any service from which you will send password to user. Store that password in SharedPreference, too. Once the user enters the correct password compare it with the stored value and if the password matches, change the value of "isFirstTime" to false. Now next time the activity is started, according to your condition the user will bypass the authentication and get started with the app.